# Automatically resolve PMD violations?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pmd

I am using `PMD` tool to find out Java code violations. I have installed an `eclipse` plug in & it is working fine. But, having lot of similar violations & resolving each separately is tedious job.

Is there any way to write some program which access specific & similar types of rules and resolve them at one go?

Answer (score 3):

There are many violations which are identified by PMD. some of these could be

> Remove Unncessary imports, unused variables etc.

So these can be removed by applying `Save Actions` in **eclipse**.

To apply Save Actions in eclipse:

go to Window->Preferences-> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions

Configure them according to you.

For more [info](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm).

Comment: @sarang, kindly accept an answer if it solves your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Aditya's excellent answer that already mentions save actions:

The PMD plugins for Eclipse offer Eclipse Quick Fixes for many PMD warnings. *PMD-Eclipse* even features a ["Quick Fix All" feature](http://pmd-eclipse.sourceforge.net/#quickfixall), which may be just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [eclipse-pmd](http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/), an alternative to the official PMD plug-in, you can fix many of the automatically resolvable problems at once.

To do this you have to open the `Problems View`, select one of the PMD problems and use the `Quick Fix` entry from the context menu. This opens the `Quick Fix Dialog` where you can click on the button `Select All` to select all occurences of the PMD problem and finally click `Finish` to resolve all those PMD problems.

However, eclipse-pmd cannot fix all problems automatically. For those problems which it cannot fix, you can use `Save Actions` (see [Aditya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20782746/3104251)) or NetBean's custom refactorings.

With [NetBean's custom refactorings](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-netbeans-71-custom) you can define your own code refactorings and apply them everywhere in your code base.

Disclaimer: I am the creator of eclipse-pmd.